# SubSonic 2.2 encrypted connection string

Tags: subsonic2.2

I want to use SubSonic on a website. I put SubSonic.DLL in the asp.net Bin folder and I've generated some classes from SubSonic Commander and put them in a DLL that is also in Bin folder. The problem is the site I'm working on encrypts their connection strings. Can SubSonic 2.2 work with an encrypted connection string? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local integrated security and avoid encryption because you have nothing to encrypt.

```
<add name="ConName" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

By default Subsonic did not have decryption, you can find the DataProvider.cs and add it by your self, or you can use the `public SharedDbConnectionScope(DataProvider dataProvider, string connectionString)` to make connections with the connection string after you decode it, but I do not think that this can help you in large scale.